# How can I insert an image inside a cloneBlock using PHPWord template processor

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

I have this in the docx template:

```
${evidence}
${date}
${image:720:480}
${/evidence}
```

I'm trying to set a string and an image that's on the local server inside a codeblock, the string gets replaced well but the image doesn't get inserted, it only shows the path to the image.

PHP code:

```
$filepath = './uploads/image.png';
$replacements = array(
            array('date' => '25-06-2022', 'image' => $filepath),
        );
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('evidence', 0, true, false, $replacements);
```

Output in the docx file:

```
25-06-2022
./uploads/image.png
```

I'm using PHPWord 0.18.3 and PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('image', $filepath); 
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('evidence', 0, true, false, $replacements);
```

Image replacements are supported:
https://phpword-zh.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/templates-processing.html